# How to remove cliping in MX Boxes flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

Is possible to remove clipping of the Box, HBox, VBox and Tile? instead of using sparks

Comment: What do you mean by clipping?  A screenshot may help to include the behavior you want and the behavior your seeing.  Some code would be nic etoo.

Answer (score 1):

There's a property for that `<mx:VBox clipContent="false"/>`
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Container.html#clipContent